# Data normalization with Python

Tags: python, csv, database-normalization

This is a sample of a csv file that will eventually be loaded to a MySQL database. The issue is that the data is not normalized, as there are multiple values in the `routes` column.

```
stop_id,on_street,cross_street,routes,boardings
49,HARRISON,PAULINA,"126, 755",1.6
50,ASHLAND,CONGRESS,"9,126",14.8
51,ASHLAND,VAN BUREN,"9,126",100.9
52,JACKSON,1900 W.(MALCOLM X COLL.),126,82.8
```

I would like to extract the `routes` column into a new csv file with `stop_id` and `route` as the column headers and there be only 1 route per row. I've already tried to import the un-normalized csv into a MySQL database but was unable to pragmatically normalize it. Any help doing this in Python before importing to the database would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to normalize? should each item in routes be a separate row? That is, `49,HARRISON,PAULINA,"126, 755",1.6` would become two rows, `49, 126` and `49, 775`?

Comment: @tdelaney that will work as well, any suggestions? In the original post I mention extracting the `routes` column into a new csv file

Comment: @Anconia - you mention extracting `routes` to `route` and I'm just looking for some clarification. Its easy to keep all of the routes together in a single row or to have only one route per row.

Comment: @tdelaney ahhh I understand - I apologize for not mentioning there should be only 1 `route` per row in the new `routes` column. OP updated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create one row per route. You can fiddle with the inner for loop if you want all routes in one row.

```
import csv
import re

sample = """stop_id,on_street,cross_street,routes,boardings
49,HARRISON,PAULINA,"126, 755",1.6
50,ASHLAND,CONGRESS,"9,126",14.8
51,ASHLAND,VAN BUREN,"9,126",100.9
52,JACKSON,1900 W.(MALCOLM X COLL.),126,82.8"""

open('sample.csv','w').write(sample)

with open('sample.csv') as sample, open('output.csv','w') as output:
    reader = csv.reader(sample)
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    # discard input header
    next(reader)
    # write output header
    writer.writerow(['stop_id', 'route'])
    # process rows
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            for route in re.split(r', *', row[3].replace('"', '')):
                writer.writerow([row[0], route])


print open('output.csv').read()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the columns that matter

```
def get_interesting_columns():
    import csv
    with open("stuff","r") as f:
        oReader = csv.reader(f)
        next(oReader) # get rid of titles line. 
                      # comment it out if you want the headings too
        for l in oReader:
            yield l[0],l[-2]
```

You can use that generator to create another csv file.

Or you can use something like SQLAlchemy to use python to execute the sql insert statements you need.